# How to remove trailing whitespace changes from a sequence of git commits

Tags: git, whitespace

I run a project on github, and someone has sent a sequence of around 20 commits as a pull request. The changes are good, but many of the commits also remove lots of trailing whitespace.

I agree trailing whitespace is bad, but the project is full of it and this isn't the place to clean it up.

Can I automatically edit the commits, to remove from each commit any whitespace only changes?

Comment: From what did you wrote I understand that you want to use git log and doesn't show whitespaces, right? If yes the use the same option `git log -w`

Comment: Nope, I want to edit the commits, to remove the whitespace-only changes -- tried to clarify question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your situation I would ask PR submitter to fix whitespaces or try to resolve that problem when merging that pull request branch into main branch using git merge options, like `git merge --ignore-space-change`. Look for more info in `man git merge`

Answer (score 0):

You could use `git revert` to undo the commits that were made. This will create new commits which reverse the edits made in the offending commits.

Then, take the changes from the now-reverted commits, strip the whitespace truncation part out, and re-apply them to the repo. This will create more new commits, to re-apply the original changes.

That's the technical answer, but I also want to suggest you think about whether this is worth doing at all.

You will end up with a bunch of new commits that basically don't do anything.
And have spent a bunch of time on this, but accomplish nothing productive.
Probably someday you will want to strip off this whitespace anyway.

Perhaps most importantly, this sort of thing has a way of causing tension between developers, many people will take it personally if you are messing about with their work when there is nothing really wrong with what they did.

I don't know the situation on your project / your team / whatever, so I may be completely wrong here. But in my experience, people often view this kind of editing as a power trip, or as petty, or something similar, and it just causes problems between the developers. So I advise considering what the political / relationship outcome of this might be, before you choose your course of action.

Comment: Just one clarification -- the commits are currently in a pull request, so I could do what you say, but I can also edit the commits before they are committed into the main code.

I would disagree with your comment about it being "nothing wrong" -- having commits which change about 20 lines of code, and about 500 lines of whitespace changes, don't belong together. Also they will cause merging issues with other branches / pull requests.

Comment: Like I said, I didn't know the situation - pull request from an outside person is very different than code already committed by one of your committers. That said, I don't have a good suggestion for how to automate this kind of edit cleanly. You have the option of asking the PR submitter to just resubmit it, too...

Answer (score 0):

I ended up overwriting each offending file with the original file from the master branch and then using a diff checker to manually add back the changes that were deletions of work I had done in the feature branch.